# Confused about some chinese remainder theorems

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, chinese-remainder-theorem

I don't know if it is appropriate to ask these kind of stuff in here.

I know the Chinese remainder theorem that if gcd(m,n)=1:

$\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$ isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

and for finite type abelian groups:

$G$ is isomorphic to $ \mathbb{Z}^r\times \mathbb{Z}/a_1\mathbb{Z} \times ... \mathbb{Z}/a_{s} \mathbb{Z} $ with $r,s,a_1...a_s$ uniques anda $a_{i+1} | a_{i}$

The problem is: Is there a theorem such that for any finite abelian group
$G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/p_{n_1} ^{m_1} \times ... \mathbb{Z}/p_{n_i} ^{m_i}$
where $p_{n_i}$ are prime numbers?

With something like $p_{n_1} ... p_{n_i} = |G|$.
(That's the main property I want to get)

If yes, could you send me a paper or link with something to read about it?
Maybe give me the conditions and the theorem?

Would you tell me anything near about it that you know?

I couldn't find this result where I searched for it, I'm pretty sure I've seen people doing it before. (I'm a beginner in group theory take it easy please.)

Comment: Yes, sure. Those are the Sylow subgroups. I am no group theorist, however; I’m sure that someone else will jump in with a good reference.

Comment: Yes, this is called the [primary decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Primary_decomposition). Note that your equation $p_{n_1} ... p_{n_i} = |G|$ should be $p_{n_1}^{m_1} \cdots p_{n_i}^{m_i} = |G|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decomposition $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{n_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p_k^{n_k}\mathbb{Z}$ when $n=p_1^{n_1}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$ follows immediately from the Chinese Remainder Theorem and induction on the number of prime factors in the factorization of $n$.

When $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}$, then $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p_1^{n_1}\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/p_2^{n_2}\mathbb{Z}$, by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, since $\gcd(p_1,p_2)=1$. When $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$, 
$$
\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/p_1^{n_1}\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}
$$
where $m=p_2^{n_2}\cdots p_k^{n_k}$, since $\gcd(p_1,m)=1$. Now, $m$ has fewer prime factors than $n$, so 
$$
\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/p_2^{n_2}\mathbb{Z}\times\cdots\times\mathbb{Z}/p_k^{n_k}\mathbb{Z}
$$
by induction.

A proof of this fact should appear in almost any introductory group theory book. Look for the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.